# How to set material on node in libgdx?

Tags: libgdx

I want to set material on node in libgdx.
My cube is completely filled with  [one texture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjM9Q.png) and I want one texture to be on one face, and another texture on another face [like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2lH4.png).
I set it with `model.materials.get(0).set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(new Texture("one.png")));`

Also i tried set material `model.getNode("plane1").parts.get(0).material.set(TextureAttribute.createDiffuse(new Texture("one.png")));`, but in this case the game crashes on startup with `NullPointerException`

Tell me please how you can solve this problem.

Full project https://github.com/D0niL19/Project2

File with a problem
https://github.com/D0niL19/Project2/blob/main/core/src/com/mygdx/game/Screens/PlayScreen.java